# Full text search failure on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I have a PostgreSQL used to index text content.
The SearchVector column is created successfully using the following code

```
UPDATE public."DocumentFiles"
SET "SearchVector" = setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.italian', coalesce("DocumentFileName", '')), 'A') 
   || setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.italian', coalesce("DocumentFileDescription", '')), 'B') 
   || setweight(to_tsvector('pg_catalog.italian', coalesce("DocumentFileContentString", '')), 'B')
WHERE "DocumentFileID" = 123;
```

The content looks like the following:

```
'011989':1A '5':7A 'cdp':2A 'contonu':10A 'elettr':6A 'grupp':8A 'impiant':5A 'manual':3A 'uso':4A
```

But if I try to run a query to get plurals or singular of *manual* (in Italian: *manuale* is one, *manuali* are 2 or more) it fails:

```
SELECT "DocumentFileID"
FROM public."DocumentFiles"
where "SearchVector"::tsvector @@ 'manuali'::tsquery;
```

return nothing

```
SELECT "DocumentFileID"
FROM public."DocumentFiles"
where "SearchVector"::tsvector @@ 'manuale'::tsquery;
```

return nothing

It only returns the record if I write exactly what is written in the searchvector field:

```
SELECT "DocumentFileID"
FROM public."DocumentFiles"
where "SearchVector"::tsvector @@ 'manual'::tsquery;
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Most certainly unrelated to your problem: but why the cast `::tsvector` if the column is already a `tsvector`? I am not really experienced with FTS, but don't you need to provide the language for the tsquery as well? `@@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.italian', 'manuale')`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it's the same syntax. I get the same behaviours with "... where "SearchVector" @@ to_tsquery('pg_catalog.italian','manuale');"

Comment: `'manual' contains 'manuali'` is false so why do you expect a match?

Comment: @kendle because 'manuali' is the plural of 'manuale'. So it must return result for both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the parameter `default_text_search_configuration` is not set to `italian`, so that a different stemming algorithm is used.

Be explicit and use `to_tsquery('italian', 'manuali')` rather than `'manuali'::tsquery`.